# array is empty i want to access array arrcolumn[]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I want to access array `arrcolumn[]` which I declared as global array.I am initializing value to array `arrcolumn[]` in `OnSuccess1()` function .I want to use `arrcolumn[]` values in  `OnSuccess()` function after initializing in OnSuccess1().
But `arrcolumn[]` is empty in `OnSuccess()` function.

```
var arrname = [];
var arrmark = [];
var arrcolumn = [];
var arr = [];
var arr1 = [];
//display function
function display() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/fetchStudent",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnErrorCall
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/fetchcolumn",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess1,
        error: OnErrorCall1
    });

    function OnSuccess1(response) {

        var objdata1 = (response.d);
        var pm1 = JSON.parse(objdata1);
        var len1 = objdata1.length;
        arr1 = $.map(pm1, function(n, i) {
            var arr_temp1 = {
                0: n.name


            }
            arrcolumn[i] = n.name;


            return arr_temp1;

        });



        arrcolumn = jQuery.grep(arrcolumn, function(value) {
            return value != removeItem;

        });
        arrcolumn = jQuery.grep(arrcolumn, function(value) {
            return value != removeItem1;

        });

        alert(arrcolumn);
    }

    function OnErrorCall1(response) {
        alert("unable to fecth");
    }

    function OnSuccess(response) {

        var objdata = (response.d);
        var pm = JSON.parse(objdata);
        var len = objdata.length;
        arr = $.map(pm, function(n, i) {
            var arr_temp = {
                0: n.name1,
                1: n.os,
                2: n.cn,
                3: n.pns,
                4: n.dbms,
                5: n.se,
                6: n.c

            }
            arrname[i] = n.name1;
            arrmark[i] = [n.os, n.cn, n.pns, n.dbms, n.se, n.c];

            return arr_temp;

        });
        //alert(arrcolumn);
        alert(arrname);
        alert(arrmark);
    }

    function OnErrorCall(response) {

        alert("error occured");
    }
}
```

Comment: This code and question are really difficult to understand, especially since you use such similar condensed variable names. What are you trying to achieve? Can you give a simple, formatted example of what works and what doesn't?

Comment: Maybe your `OnSuccess1` is executed before `OnSuccess`? Ajax is async and will take variable amount of time to complete

Comment: You can't guarantee which will finish first, make them in series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no guarantee that `OnSuccess1` will be called after `OnSuccess`. If you need both pieces of information before you can do the work, you need to wait for both calls to complete.

One easy way to do that is jQuery's [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
$.when(
    $.ajax(/*...*/), // The first call
    $.ajax(/*...*/)  // The second call
).then(function(result1, result2) {
    // Both calls are done now. Use `result1` (the result of the
    // first call) and `result2` (the result of the second) here
});
```

The calls will run in parallel, but the handler at the end won't be run until both calls complete.

Comment: *(Doh! If you see "before" rather than "after" in the first sentence, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Why didn't you dupehammer this question to [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3853934)

Comment: @Gothdo: I don't think it's a dupe of that. It may well be a dupe of something else to which `$.when` or `Promise.all` is the answer, but the OP was clearly waiting for the callbacks before doing their work. They just didn't realize the callbacks may not be in order. I got through the first three pages on [this search](/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bjquery%5d%20wait%20for%20multiple%20ajax%20complete) and gave up.